# HandleException doesn't get executed

Tags: wcf, exception, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm working on WCF Data Services and I want to put custom errors once I encounter one. Through my research I am pointed to overriding the HandleException method so that I can catch any exception that I will encounter but that method doesn't get executed if ever there are errors. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a sample code that I use to force the exception.

```
    throw new DataServiceException("Testing");
```

Here's the override method HandleException.

```
    protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
    {
        throw new DataServiceException("HandleException");
    }
```

Here's my configuration.

```
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.DataServiceBehavior.AcceptProjectionRequests = true;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
```

Please helpppppp!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us where did you put the exception thrown code?

The following code puts it into a custom Action, the Handler can be called successfully.

```
    protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\time.txt", FileMode.Append))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }

    }

    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("S1", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.DataServiceBehavior.AcceptProjectionRequests = true;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }

    [WebGet]
    public int S1()
    {
        throw new DataServiceException("ui1");
    }
```

Also, if I put exception in the IRequestHandler logic, the handler method would also be called.